# "Floors" for a house

Tags: word-usage, nouns

When talking, for example, about an apartment building, you ca say "The building has eight floors". But when talking about a house that got two "floors", do you still call them *floors* in English? Or is there a different word for "floors" in a regular house?

Comment: related: [Difference between floor and storey](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204727/difference-between-floor-and-storey)

Comment: The simple answer is that we still call them floors. However, this seems like a question for the English Language Learners stack exchange rather than this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that there is a difference between UK and US usage with respect to numbering floors. A two-storey building in the UK is said to have a ground floor and a first floor. In the US the same building would be described as having a first floor and a second floor.

In Britain, when we are talking about a two-storey house (home), we normally speak about 'upstairs' and 'downstairs'.  In a two-storey commercial building we might (in Britain) talk about the ground floor and the first floor.

Note also that 'storey' in the UK is spelled 'story' in the USA.

**[Storey vs. story - grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/spelling/storey-story/)**

Answer (score 1):

The words *floor*,  *story*, and *level* are used more or less interchangeably to refer to the separate "layers" in any building.

Answer (score 0):

*Floor* is a legitimate English word to be used with reference to a house. However, *stories* (a synonym of *floors*) is more popular in terms of usage, at least in American fiction.

Comment: Note that in the UK we say, 'storey' and 'storeys' in this context.

Comment: I can't say I have noticed any significant difference in usage between "floor" and "story" to describe the levels of a building. There /may/ be a slight preference for floor in taller and/or buildings that are not single-family homes, but I am in no way sure enough about this call it more than a vague impression on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the terms of ''floor'', ''floor level'' and ''storey\story'' apply no matter whether the building in question is a one storey shed or cottage or 100 storey high-rise. Now, what levels qualify as ''floors'' depends on local law and custom. For example, In some areas, basements are considered floor levels and not in others.