# Basement, Ground floor, _____, Penthouse. A word for the middle floors?

Tags: single-word-requests

When the line is drawn at these locations - i.e. it only matters that it's above the ground floor but it isn't the penthouse, what is a single word to refer to those floors as?

For example: Alex lives in a basement bedroom, Bob lives in a ground floor bedroom, Charlie lives in a ____ bedroom, Delta lives in a penthouse studio.

Comment: Would "intermediate floor" work?

Comment: I was going to suggest *upper floor*, but when I googled it I got lots of porn results, so I guess it's a euphemism I wasn't familiar with.

Comment: @Barmar 'Lots' is very misleading as it is in this case. There are a couple of links to questionable websites in the top first ten sites from google, but almost all of the other google hits use 'upper floor' as 'floors above the ground floor'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mid-level

adjective
1. middle-level.

> Alex lives in a basement bedroom, Bob lives in a ground floor bedroom, Charlie lives in a mid-level bedroom ( *but she has an upper floor fetish* ), Delta lives in a penthouse studio.

It works with the context in the example you have given. All though to just say, my best friend live in a mid-level apartment, would be ambiguous as it could refer to class or economic status or size.

Answer (score -1):

Storey, floor or level.

Sounds like you might be confusing terminology a little though. A penthouse isn't the top floor or top storey in every building, only in residential/hotel buildings (and again, not all residential buildings have a penthouse).

Comment: Storey is probably the word you're looking for though, it's the only one that is consistently used to refer to levels that aren't basement or ground floors.

eg. The first storey is first floor above ground.

Comment: Or Story in AmE

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/204727/51214, in particular this answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/238411/51214.

Answer (score -1):

They are the upper floors or the higher floors.  That is as precise as we can get, I believe.